# How to hide a MatrixRow in SSRS 2005 based on an expression?

Tags: reporting-services, visibility

I was wondering if someone can tell me how I can hide a row in a matrix on an SSRS 2005 report. I have tried hiding the specific TextBoxes, but when I do that, I still get whitespace where the TextBoxes would appear, which is pretty worthless.

According to research I have done online, there is supposed to be a visibility/hidden property when I right click the row header and go to properties, but I don't see that there. Below is a  link to a screenshot of what I get for the properties:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/696/ssrs.jpg

Where do I find this property? When I expanded all the groups, I didn't see anything related to visibility.

Is it possible to hide this row bases on an expression? Please let me know.

Thanks

---

New users apparently cannot answer their own questions without waiting 8 hours. It said to use the edit function instead. I'll marked this as answered later.

I think I found what I was looking for. I got the desired result anyway. Since I hate coming to posts and seeing "Thanks, I figured it out" without any other detail...

Right Click on the Matrix, that is to say, right click on the dotted line with the resizing handles that outlines the matrix. After that click properties. This should bring up a Matrix Properties dialog box. Go the Groups tab (5th over). To change the visibility of a row/column, click the "Edit" button. This brings up another dialog box. Visibility is the 4th tab.

Hope that saves someone a headache.

Comment: Yes, you save my headchache, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found what I was looking for. I got the desired result anyway. Since I hate coming to posts and seeing "Thanks, I figured it out" without any other detail...

Right Click on the Matrix, that is to say, right click on the dotted line with the resizing handles that outlines the matrix. After that click properties. This should bring up a Matrix Properties dialog box. Go the Groups tab (5th over). To change the visibility of a row/column, click the "Edit" button. This brings up another dialog box. Visibility is the 4th tab.

Hope that saves someone a headache.